# Как написать планировщик потоков (алгоритм планирования ресурсов) на C#? How to write a thread scheduler (resource scheduling algorithm)in C #?

Tags: c#, json, многопоточность, selenium, multiprocessing

У меня есть задание сделать парсинг новостей в вк с помощью селениума и c#, затем сохранить данные в json и считать. Эту часть я сделал и осталась та часть в которой мне нужно создать семафоры и мониторы для каждого файла и создать свой собственный алгоритм планирования ресурсов. Есть 3 независимые функции Js.save1, Js.save2 и Js.save3 каждая из функций сохраняет данные в свой созданный json файл (f1, f2 и f3). Также есть функция, которая пытается прочитать данные из всех трех файлов по очереди. 4 функции - 4 потока. Как их синхронизировать, написать планировщик с семафорами и мониторами для каждого файла, алгоритм планирования ресурсов. Просто я совсем не могу понять как все это реализовать, может быть у вас есть как-нибудь идей или советы. Спасибо.

I have the task of parsing news in VK using selenium and c #, then save the data in json and count. I did this part and the part remained in which I need to create semaphores and monitors for each file and create my own resource planning algorithm. There are 3 independent functions Js.save1, Js.save2 and Js.save3, each of the functions saves data in its own created json file (f1, f2 and f3). There is also a function that tries to read data from all three files in turn. 4 functions - 4 threads. How to synchronize them, write a scheduler with semaphores and monitors for each file, an algorithm for scheduling resources. I just can’t understand at all how to implement all this, maybe you have some ideas or advice. Thank.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Threading;


namespace Csharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static object locker = new object();

        [DataContract]
        class Post
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string id;
            [DataMember]
            public string[] arrOfImageLinks;
            [DataMember]
            public string[] arrOfLinks;
            [DataMember]
            public string text;

            public Post() { id = ""; arrOfImageLinks = new string[0]; arrOfLinks = new string[0]; text = ""; }

            public Post(string id, string[] arrOfImageLinks, string[] arrOfLinks, string text)
            {
                this.id = id;
                this.arrOfImageLinks = arrOfImageLinks;
                this.arrOfLinks = arrOfLinks;
                this.text = text;
            }
        }

        class WorkWithJson
        {
            public Post[] posts;
            public bool saveF1 = true;
            public bool saveF2 = true;
            public bool saveF3 = true;

            public WorkWithJson(ref Post[] posts)
            {
                this.posts = posts;
            }

            public void save1()
            {
                var id_text = new SortedDictionary<string, string[]> { };

                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Thread 1");
                            id_text[posts[i].id] = new string[1];
                            id_text[posts[i].id][0] = posts[i].text;
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("________________________exception_save1_______________________");
                    }
                    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter1 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SortedDictionary<string, string[]>));

                    using (FileStream f1 = new FileStream("f1.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        jsonFormatter1.WriteObject(f1, id_text);
                    }

            }

            public void save2()
            {
                var id_linksInsideText = new SortedDictionary<string, string[]> { };


                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.Length; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string[] arrOfLinks = new string[posts[i].arrOfLinks.Length];

                            for (int j = 0; j < posts[i].arrOfLinks.Length; j++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Thread 2");
                                arrOfLinks[j] = posts[i].arrOfLinks[j];
                            }

                            id_linksInsideText[posts[i].id] = arrOfLinks;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("________________________exception_save2_______________________");
                        }
                    }
                    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter2 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SortedDictionary<string, string[]>));

                    using (FileStream f2 = new FileStream("f2.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        jsonFormatter2.WriteObject(f2, id_linksInsideText);
                    }

            }

            public void save3()
            {
                var id_imageLinks = new SortedDictionary<string, string[]> { };

                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.Length; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string[] arrOfImageLinks = new string[posts[i].arrOfImageLinks.Length];
                            for (int j = 0; j < posts[i].arrOfImageLinks.Length; j++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Thread 3");
                                arrOfImageLinks[j] = posts[i].arrOfImageLinks[j];
                            }

                            id_imageLinks[posts[i].id] = arrOfImageLinks;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("________________________exception_save3_______________________");
                        }
                    }

                    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter3 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SortedDictionary<string, string[]>));

                    using (FileStream f3 = new FileStream("f3.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        jsonFormatter3.WriteObject(f3, id_imageLinks);
                    }

            }

            public void read()
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SortedDictionary<string, string[]>));

                void read1() {

                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------id-text---------------------------");
                    Console.ResetColor();

                    using (FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("f1.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        SortedDictionary<string, string[]> dict1 = (SortedDictionary<string, string[]>)jsonFormatter.ReadObject(fs1);

                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string txt = dict1[posts[i].id][0];
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.WriteLine($"id: {posts[i].id}");
                            Console.ResetColor();

                            Console.WriteLine($"-- {txt}");
                        }
                    }
                }

                void read2()
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------id-links-inside-text--------------");
                    Console.ResetColor();

                    using (FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("f2.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        SortedDictionary<string, string[]> dict2 = (SortedDictionary<string, string[]>)jsonFormatter.ReadObject(fs2);

                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string[] arr = dict2[posts[i].id];

                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.WriteLine($"id: {posts[i].id}");
                            Console.ResetColor();

                            if (arr.Length == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("--");
                                continue;
                            }

                            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                                Console.WriteLine($"-- {arr[j]}");
                        }
                    }
                }

                void read3()
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------id-image-links--------------------");
                    Console.ResetColor();

                    using (FileStream fs3 = new FileStream("f3.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        SortedDictionary<string, string[]> dict3 = (SortedDictionary<string, string[]>)jsonFormatter.ReadObject(fs3);

                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string[] arr = dict3[posts[i].id];

                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.WriteLine($"id: {posts[i].id}");
                            Console.ResetColor();

                            if (arr.Length == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("--");
                                continue;
                            }

                            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
                                Console.WriteLine($"-- {arr[j]}");
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\n~End_of_reading");
                }

                read1();
                read2();
                read3();
            }
        };

        static void deleteJsonFiles()
        {
            File.Delete(@"f1.json");
            File.Delete(@"f2.json");
            File.Delete(@"f3.json");
        }

        static Post[] dataCapture()
        {
            const int CountOfPosts = 10;

            Post[] posts = new Post[CountOfPosts];

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/badyi/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
            ChromeDriver chr = new ChromeDriver(options);
            chr.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://vk.com/feed");

            var arrOfPosts = chr.FindElements(By.ClassName("wall_post_cont"));

            for (int i = 0; i < CountOfPosts; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    string wp_link = arrOfPosts[i].GetAttribute("id");

                    string post_id = wp_link.Remove(0, 4);

                    string refe1 = "#wpt-" + post_id + " > div.wall_post_text";
                    string postText;
                    try
                    {
                        postText = chr.FindElement(By.CssSelector(refe1)).Text;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        postText = "";
                    }

                    string refe2 = "#wpt-" + post_id + " > div.page_post_sized_thumbs.clear_fix > a";
                    var imagesInside = chr.FindElements(By.CssSelector(refe2));

                    string refe3 = "#wpt-" + post_id + " > div.wall_post_text > a";
                    var linksInside = chr.FindElements(By.CssSelector(refe3));

                    string[] arrOfImageLinks = new string[imagesInside.Count()];
                    string[] arrOfLinks = new string[linksInside.Count()];

                    char[] ch = { '"', ')' };
                    for (int j = 0; j < imagesInside.Count(); j++)
                        arrOfImageLinks[j] = (imagesInside[j].GetCssValue("background-image").Remove(0, 5)).Trim(ch);

                    for (int j = 0; j < linksInside.Count(); j++)
                        arrOfLinks[j] = linksInside[j].GetAttribute("href");

                    Post p = new Post(post_id, arrOfImageLinks, arrOfLinks, postText);
                    posts[i] = p;

                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("________________________exception_main_______________________");
                }
            }
            return posts;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
            {

            deleteJsonFiles();

            Post[] posts = dataCapture();

            WorkWithJson Js = new WorkWithJson(ref posts);

            Thread myThread1 = new Thread(Js.save1);
            Thread myThread2 = new Thread(Js.save2);
            Thread myThread3 = new Thread(Js.save3);

            myThread1.Start();
            myThread2.Start();
            myThread3.Start();

            //readJson_and_print(ref posts);
            Thread myThread4 = new Thread(Js.read);

            myThread4.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а в чем смысл писать в файл и потом читать из файла? Нельзя в этой схеме обойтись без файла?

Comment: @tym32167 это необходимо по заданию.

Comment: и зачем читать в отдельном потоке? Ведь вы можете начать попытку чтения в момент, когда ещё не произошла запись. Нельзя читать 3 раза в тех же потоках, что и запись, уже после записи?

Comment: Имеет ли смысл использовать потоки доя этого? Может тогда использовать таски, чтобы читать точно после записи? Почему бы таски не выполнить на пуле потоков вместо ручного создания потоков?

Comment: Я бы просто взял из каждой вашей задачи писал бы в свою отдельную `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, а затем читал бы из нее и писал в файл и на экран.